# Error redirection not working

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am trying to pipe the output of a script to a text file.

This works:

```
MyScript > c:\output.txt
```

The problem with this is that errors are not included in the output in the text file (on screen they are).

When do this:

```
MyScript 2>&1 c:\output.txt
```

No file is created (but I still see everything on the screen).

I'm using Powershell 3.0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is:

```
MyScript > c:\output.txt 2>&1
```

The "> c:\output.txt" redirects STDOUT to a file

The 2>&1 redirects STDERR to STDOUT

When you've already done the STDOUT redirection, the result is redirection of both STDOUT and STDERR to c:\output.txt

With only "2>&1 c:\output.txt" you're redirecting stderr to stdout, but letting stdout still output to console, and merely supplying c:\output.txt as an unused parameter to your script.

Comment: I searched high and low and no example I found showed it like this. I appreciate it!

Comment: Glad it helped, this behavior is not PowerShell specific either, it works with cmd too.